# Parse elements from a List of Lists in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a list of a list with 3 strings like *tst3*, and I need to parse all the list and use the first and second arguments(strings) in *function*. But the map doesn't work well with it

> ```
>   function a b = do {putStrLn (a ++ "stuff");
>                      putStrLn b;}
>
>
>   tst3 = [["aaa","aaaaaaaa","112121"],["asda","a22","aaax"]]
>   fx2 s = map fx3 (tst3)
>       where fx3 s = function (s!!0)(s!!1)
>
>
>
> Couldn't match expected type `[a]' against inferred type `Char'
>   Expected type: [[[a]]]
>   Inferred type: [[Char]]
> In the second argument of `map', namely `(tst3)'
> In the expression: map fx3 (tst3)
> ```

Is there a better way to do this ?
I can use [("aa","bb"),("ww","cc"),("jj","oooo")] if it gets easier

Thanks

Comment: The type of `function` is off, but without seeing it we probably can't tell why.

Comment: We need to see the source of `function`.

Comment: That compiles without problems.

Comment: Using `tst::[(String,String,String)]` instead of `::[[String]]` is definitely cleaner if all list elements are supposed to have exactly three strings in them. Or, if you indeed use only the first two, `tst::[(String,String)]`. And either way, you should consider extracting these strings with pattern matching rather than with `head`/`fst`/... or – worst of all! – the `!!` operator you use now: `fx3 (s:s':_) = function s s'` or `fx3 (s,s',_) = function s s'`. In fact, for `[(String,String)]` you can simply write `fx3 = uncurry function`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing *wrong* with what you've written there, however it's not actually very meaningful. You're transforming a list of some kind of data into a list of IO actions, but that alone doesn't do anything: what you probably want is *perform* these actions for every element of the list. This kind of thing is typically done with `mapM_`:

```
function :: String -> String -> IO()
function a b = do putStrLn (a ++ "stuff")   -- there's no reason to use curly
                  putStrLn b                -- brackets here


tst::[(String,String,String)]
tst3 = [("aaa","aaaaaaaa","112121"),("asda","a22","aaax")]

fx2 :: a -> IO()
fx2 s = mapM_ fx3 (tst3)      -- note that this s parameter is not used at all
    where fx3 (s,s',_) = function s s'
```

Comment: It's Perfect thanks!
I didn't know **mapM** but it works, using **map** wouldn't